# Short story about a wanted man infected by a parasite

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I've googled variations of the below and got '10 horror movies' etc.

- I read it thirty years ago as a child, so early to mid 80's.
- It's probably a short story.
- The man is about to be executed or is wanted by the police.
- He's infected by a parasite/symbiant.
- The parasite notes that it's nice to see in colors.
- The man escapes from pursuers by teleporting.
- It isn't *The Jaunt* by Stephen King.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details.

Comment: I've actually used the guide before posting. This is it. I dont have any more details. I was around 10 when I read it.

Comment: Sorry that's sort of a stock response as most people are unaware of the guide, but kudos to you for using it. The details look uniquely identifiable. I myself am not a good identifier, but I'm almost certain one of the "experts" will come along and solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Insidekick** by J. F. Bone
https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41279

*The man is about to be executed or is wanted by the police*

> Satisfied
> that it was empty except
> for Fred Kemmer and himself, he
> sidled up to the Earthman’s desk
> and hissed conspiratorially in his
> ear, “Sir, this Johnson is a spy!
> Is it permitted to slay him?”
> “It is permitted,” Kemmer said
> in a tone suitable to the gravity
> of the occasion.

*He's infected by a parasite/symbiant*

> CURIOUSLY, the Zark sent out a pseudopod of its substance
> through the open mouth of its disguise.
> The faintly glittering thread
> oozed downward and struck Albert’s
> head beside his right eye.
> Without pausing, the thread sank
> through skin and connective tissue,
> circled the eyeball and located
> the optic nerve. It raced inward
> along the nerve trunk, split at the
> optic chiasma, and entered the
> corpora quadrigemina where it
> branched into innumerable microscopic
> filaments that followed the
> main neural paths of the man’s
> brain, probing the major areas of
> thought and reflex.

> The Zark quivered with pleasure.
> The creature was beautifully
> complex, and, more important, untenanted.
> He would make an interesting
> host.

*The parasite notes that it's nice to see in colors.*

> Color was something new to
> the Zark. Its previous hosts had
> been color blind, and the symbiont
> wallowed in an orgy of bright sensation.

*The man escapes from pursuers by teleporting*

> He suddenly felt alone and helpless,
> wishing desperately for a quiet
> place where he could dress his
> wound and be safe from the eyes
> he knew were inspecting him. He
> was too conspicuous. The pajamas
> were out of place on the street. Undoubtedly
> natives were hurrying to
> report him to the IC.

> His mind turned to his room
> in the hostel with its well-fitted
> wardrobe and its first-aid kit —
> and again came that instant of utter
> darkness — and then he was
> standing in the middle of his room
> facing the wardrobe that held his
> clothing.

> HE felt no surprise this time.
> He knew what had happened.
> Something within his body was
> acting like a tiny Distorter, transporting
> him through hyperspace in
> the same manner that a starship’s
> engine room warped it through the
> folds of the normal space-time continuum.
> There was nothing really
> strange about it It was a power
> which he *should* have — which any
> normal man should have. The fact
> that he didn’t have it before was
> of no consequence, and the fact
> that other men didn’t have it now
> merely made them abnormal.

The story can be found in the Internet Archive

https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v17n03_1959-02

Comment: Clearly you have nailed it.  I am deleting my answer.

Comment: Bravo, sir. I was worried I was misremembering some of the point and would lead people astray but apparently I remembered correctly. Amazing.